# Django Admin site paginator does not appear

Tags: django, django-admin, django-pagination

I'm setting up a django paginator in the Django Admin Site in order to display the elements 30by30 on the changelist. To do so, I'm using "list_per_page=30" on the DocumentAdmin.

It works fine on Firefox, but the paginator doesn't appear on Safari, either in iMac, iPad or iPhone... so I can only see the first 30 elements. However, it does appear when I reduce the amount of elements I want to display, for instance, 8. I have similar problems using Chrome.

Am I missing something? Any help is really welcome.

Thanks for your time.

```
class DocumentAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    change_list_filter_template = "admin/filter_listing.html"
    list_display = ('cover', 'name', 'printed', 'sent', 'opened', 'category', 'groups', 'related_docs')
    list_display_links = None
    search_fields = ('name', )
    list_filter = (GroupFilter, CategoryFilter, 'printed', 'sent', 'opened', )
    list_editable = ('sent', 'opened', 'order')

    list_per_page = 30
```

Comment: show us `DocumentAdmin` class code plz

Comment: which version of django and python you used?

Comment: if you comment out `change_list_filter_template` problem still persists?

Comment: @mymusise Python 2.7.10, Django (1, 7, 10, 'final', 0)

Comment: @devxplorer it still persists. Checking the html elements I've seen that paginator has an inline style "display:none". I think that some kind of internal script adds this, since I only hide the paginator in one case and I already checked that this case is not the problem.

Comment: Problem solved, there were two cases where the paginator was hidden, but one of them was in another module and I didn't check it. Thanks guys!